# Oracle 11g Virtual Column derived from query

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, virtual-column

Is it possible to create a virtual column based off a query to another table? - something like the following

```
DateTable               
DateDt   StatusCd           
7/31     
8/1      CURRENT
8/2      
8/5
8/6
8/7 

OtherTable
Column1
Column2
VIRTUALDate = Select DateDt from DateTable where DateTable.StatusCd = 'CURRENT'
```

I can go more in depth in the example if needed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

From [the documentation](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php):

> The column_expression in the AS clause has the following restrictions:
>
> - It cannot refer to another virtual column by name.
> - Any columns referenced in column_expression must be defined on the same table.
> - It can refer to a deterministic user-defined function, but if it does, then you cannot use the virtual column as a partitioning key
>     column.

So it can't refer to another table; and you can't have a function that does a look up on another table because that would not be deterministic.

You can use a view to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: In the user-defined function, if I add some querying(from another table) and returns the result.
Is it feasible?

Comment: @meadlai - but then the function wouldn't be deterministic, so no. (I guess if the query was a simple look-up against a static table you could still abuse this by declaring the function as deterministic anyway, but nothing is truly static so it's dangerous, and better solutions exist - use a view or just join when querying).

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole  I add extra column to solve this problem.